# how to place location icon on mapkit objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am new in objective c.I have created a project which consist of a mapView

In ViewController.h in ny project,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MapKit/MapKit.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

In ViewController.m file i have viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
         mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

I want to give coordinates of more then one location in my code, and I want to show loc.png icon on map corresponding to those coordinates. how can I accomplish this task? And how to zoom the map to maximum scale ?
Form this link you can download my sample project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnZGZnU1ZfbjZMRWs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had working on your question and this are my results, use this code, now Iam using a custom class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol

***EDITED***

**Place.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Place : NSObject<MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

// Title and subtitle for use by selection UI.
@property (nonatomic, nullable) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, nullable) NSString *subtitle;

-(id)initWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinates andName:(NSString*)name;

@end
```

**Place.m**

```
#import "Place.h"


@implementation Place
@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle;

-(id)initWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinates andName:(NSString*)name
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        [self setTitle:name];
        [self setCoordinate:coordinates];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**Modified Code**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Place.h"

@interface ViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property NSMutableArray * arrayOfLocations;
@end

@implementation ViewController 
@synthesize mapView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
         mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;

        self.arrayOfLocations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[Place alloc] initWithCoordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.416691, -3.700345) andName:@"MADRID"],
                         [[Place alloc] initWithCoordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(35.416691, -3.700345) andName:@"SOMEWARE IN THE MAP"],
                         [[Place alloc] initWithCoordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(35.416691, -40.700345) andName:@"SOMEWARE IN THE MAP1"],
                         [[Place alloc] initWithCoordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(20.416691, -50.700345) andName:@"SOMEWARE IN THE MAP2"], nil];

    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.arrayOfLocations];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (nullable MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView * annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"testAnnotationView"];
    if(annotationView == nil){
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"testAnnotationView"];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loc.png"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true;
    }

    return annotationView;
}

@end
```

Hope this helps you,

***This is how it looks***

[image]

Comment: it is displaying image (loc.png) for last item of arrayOfLocations .it should display loc.png for each item of arrayOfLocations.

Comment: I also want to location title displayed on image when hovered on loc.png

Comment: sample code is at this link: :https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnSy1rbkVhT0VleG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @frincit you are having this problem because you are adding incorrectly the items to NSMutableArray, I will post an example with more than one item

Comment: How i can zoom the map to maximum scale ?